# Вывести значение из Firebase без функции

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
ref.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('name').on("value", 
    console.log(snapshot.val()); //Олег
});

console.log(name); // Олег
```

Соответственно, как мне вывести имя в консоль и быть вне функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заведите переменную, область видимости которой подразумевает доступность вне вашей функции. Внутри функции присваивайте ей значение, вне - выводите

в качестве общего примера:

```
var my_var;

(function(){
    my_var = 'Hello';
})();

console.log(my_var);
```

если требуется вывод после наступления определённого события:

```
function my_func(val) {
console.log(val);
}

ref.child('users').child(authData.uid).child('balance').on("value", function(snapshot) {
   my_func(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: а можно пожалуйста пример?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hvzz6sdh/

Comment: @alexanderbarakin сделано

Comment: не работает к сожалению https://jsfiddle.net/97jne36x/

Comment: В вашем случае переменной присваивается значение по какому-то событию, а не линейно. То есть console.log() за пределами функции выполняется раньше, чем происходит присваивание нужного вам значения внутри обработчика. Вызывайте внутри него какую-нибудь функцию, которая будет выполнять необходимые вам действия (например https://jsfiddle.net/97jne36x/1/ или https://jsfiddle.net/97jne36x/2/)